# no eth0 Network error fetching interface information: Device not found

Tags: networking, server, ethernet, vps

How I can find my eth0 on my Ubuntu VPS?

```
$ ifconfig -a
  lo        
  Link encap:Local Loopback
  inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
  inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
  UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
  RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
  TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
  collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
  RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

  venet0
  Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
  inet addr:127.0.0.2  P-t-P:127.0.0.2  Bcast:0.0.0.0  
  Mask:255.255.255.255
  inet6 addr: 2a05:8b81:1000:180::e6a2/64 Scope:Global
  UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
  RX packets:85107 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
  TX packets:9331 errors:0 dropped:8 overruns:0 carrier:0
  collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
  RX bytes:125961662 (125.9 MB)  TX bytes:943045 (943.0 KB)

  venet0:0  
  Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
  inet addr:185.82.22.101  P-t-P:185.82.22.101  Bcast:185.82.22.101  
  Mask:255.255.255.255
  UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

Comment: According to your `ifconfig -a` your interfaces is called venet0 (for local host) and vnet0:0 for network to  the world .. and it seems that the last one is configured with the correct ipv4 ip-address.

Comment: What do I have to do it looks like in the example?

Answer (score 0):

You should change the contents of `/etc/network/interfaces` to reflect the actual interface names in the output from `ifconfig -a`.

You can then use:

```
ifconfig vnet0:0
```

Which should work now... let me know how you get on.

Comment: vnet0:0: error fetching interface information: Device not found

Comment: Make sure you either restart the networking service or reboot the machine for the changes to /etc/network/interface to take effect.